Maven: org.codehaus.plexus is not working
My project is using a group of org.codehaus.pleuxs maven dependencies.

plexus
plexus-archiver
plexus-classworlds
plexus-compiler
plexus-compiler-api
plexus-compiler-javac
plexus-compiler-manager
plexus-compilers
plexus-component-annotations
plexus-components
plexus-container-default
plexus-containers
plexus-interactivity-api
plexus-interpolation
plexus-io
plexus-utils

But while building we are getting the following error while running mvn clean install

Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.1:copy (copy-misc-runtime) on project MyServer: Execution copy-misc-runtime of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.1:copy failed: A required class was missing while executing org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.1:copy: org/codehaus/plexus/components/io/resources/PlexusIoResourceCollection

To fix this I deleted entire repository folder in .m2 but the same error is showing.

Update:
Java version: openjdk version "1.8.0_292"
Maven version: Apache Maven 3.9.1
pom.xml used
<pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.plexus</groupId>
                    <artifactId>plexus-archiver</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0-alpha-11</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</pluginManagement>


First why is your project using those deps.. ? Furthermore I see an ancient old plugin version 2.1 of the maven-dependency-plugin which is of 2015!! Which Maven version, JDK version etc. do you use? Can you show us the pom file?

@khmarbaise sure, I will update the details, the reason for these old versions are because this is a very old legacy project where the code is huge and interdependent on some older versions, updating the version is not feasible.

If you use such ancient old Plugin you can not use Maven 3.9.X (https://maven.apache.org/docs/3.9.0/release-notes.html) you have to stick with Maven 3.8.X (please check before that I'm not 100% sure about). I would recomment to upgrade your plugins in your build...then you can use Maven 3.9.X..  also the JDK 1.8. is old at the moment (https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/8all-relnotes.html)

The dependencies you have mentioned are used by plugin not by your own project?  is that correct?

@khmarbaise they are used in both ways.

What do you mean by that? You have a project which is a plugin? If so upgrade that plugin to most recent versions (incl. all deps etc.) ... So one project is a plugin and one is a application project. An application project should never rely on those deps..
